# Textpad 6.1 opens new blank tab when opening document (Windows XP SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, textpad

I have installed Textpad 6 on my machine, and whenever I open a document with textpad, a new blank tab opens by default and cursor points to the blank file.

I have to manually point to my document and close the blank tab. I remember in earlier version of textpad, whenever I used to open a document, it used to point to the same by default and no blank tab was being opened. How can I restore this behaviour?